# PHP - MySQL - and JPagination

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the JPagination to paginig results from a MySQL database The code works, but I am getting the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginate\page.php on line 11`

Files

**index.php**

```
  [...]
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.paginate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php require('db.php'); ?>
<?php require('page.php'); ?>
<div class="demo">
<div id="pagetxt">
<?php
$consulta = "select * from rec order by id desc limit 0,10";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<p>" .$row["id"]."<a>".$row["titulo"]."</a></p>";
}
?>
</div>
<div id="demo1"></div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo1").paginate({

            count: "<?php echo $page;?>",
            start:1,
            display:10,
            border:true,
            border_color:'#BEF8B8',
            text_color:'#79B5E3',
            background_color:'#E3F2E1',
            border_hover_color:'#68BA64',
            text_hover_color:'#2573AF',
            background_hover_color:'#CAE6C6',
            images:false,
            mouse:'press',
            onChange:function(page){
            $("#pagetxt").load("page.php?page="+page);
            }
        })
})

</script>
</body>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");


$consultab = "select count(*) as c from rec";
$resultb = mysqli_query($con, $consultab);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultb);
$total = $row['c'];
$pagesize = 10;
$page = ceil($total/$pagesize);
$start = ($_GET['page'] - 1)*$pagesize;

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$consulta = "select * from rec order by id asc limit $start,$pagesize";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<p>".$row["id"]."<a>
".$row["titulo"]."</a></p>";
}
}
?>
```

If i manually write index.php?page=1 in the address bar the error disappear but i get 20 items in the pagination, the first 10 items and the last 10 items.

This question seems a duplicate but it's not, my problem not only consists in an undefined index error . I am new to php and mysql, and what I need is to find out how I can fix this code to display results correctly. Could someone help me?

Comment: This question seems a duplicate but it's not, my problem not only consists in an undefined index error . I am new to php and mysql, and what I need is to find out how I can fix this code to display results correctly.

Comment: Also you can vote to reopen your own question, it decreases the needed votes by one.